# Feature selection methods comparison

Tags: classification, t-test, feature-selection, pattern-recognition

I recently run a project that involves a feature selection step before further pattern recognition.

The number of features for our data set is very large and instead of running greedy forward/backward feature selection. I simply run the Student T-test on the features and ranking them according to the p-values to find the most 'powerful' features for my classification task.

However, I got some argument from my colleagues that this kind of Student T-test based feature selection method is not optimal. For example, the forward or backward feature selection can find the best features until the classification performance can't be improved (therefore, they can find the optimal feature subset).

I am wondering if anyone knows some references (papers, thesis) that run some experiments to prove that Student T-test based feature selection method can perform similarly like the exhaustive methods? Or is there any mathematical background to underpin this?

Thanks a lot.

A.

I found a relevant paper on PlosOne:
[A paper](http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3adoi/10.1371/journal.pone.0028210)

Comment: Just a comment: The exhaustive methods that you are mentioning are not really exhaustive. They are still greedy. Let $F_k$ be the optimal set of features among all subsets $F$, such that $|F| = k$. Then $F_{k +1}$ may not be of form $F_k\cup\{f\}$ for some feature $f$.